# Returning Empty Hash - Perl

Tags: perl

Hi I'm trying to create a json by checking if some url's are valid(for 404 errors), then I use the id of these urls and pass them on to the hash, which I then encode and write it into a json file. But for some reason it keeps returning an empty hash `{}`

Here's my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;
use feature qw(say);

my $json = JSON->new();

my $count = 400;
my $url = 'http://domain.com/media/';

my %cards = ();

for (my $id = 0; $id <= $count; $id++) {
       my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new();
       my $response = $lwp->head($url . $id . '.swf');
        if ($response->code != 404) {
             $cards{card_id} = $id;
             $cards{coins} = 10;
        }
}

my $data = $json->pretty->encode(\%cards);

open FILEHANDLE, '>>', 'cards.json';
say FILEHANDLE $data;
close FILEHANDLE;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Time to use debug tools ? At least `perl -d script.pl` to see what's happening step by step

Comment: The syntax highlighting in your editor, or at least here, should show you a missing closing single quote.

Comment: I tried using Data::Dumper on $response it seems to work properly, for files that dont exist, it returns 404's. Sorry about the syntax thing, I accidently removed it while pasting the code here.

Comment: By the way: your hash %cards will store only last (max) ID found in the range 0..400. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

1. Think, all your iterations in "for" are ending with 404. (Recheck URLs manually.)
2. Also be aware that you'll get the only last non-404 item in your hash. (Is it that what you expect to have?)

Comment: Only a few ids are ending with a 404, I actually want all the non 404 ids to be in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
         $cards{card_id} = $id;
         $cards{coins} = 10;
```

to be something more like this

```
         $cards{$id} = 10;
```

yes?